# Grails: setting transient fields in the map constructor

Tags: json, grails, constructor, grails-orm, transient

I'm trying to persist Maps of properties as single JSON-encoded columns, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106384/persisting-maps-and-lists-of-properties-as-json-in-grails).

The problem I'm having is that apparently **transient properties cannot be set in the default map constructor**. Given any transient field:

```
class Test {
    //...
    String foo
    static transients = ['foo']
}
```

It seems that the map constructor (which Grails overrides in various ways) simply discards transient fields:

```
groovy:000> t = new Test(foo:'bar')
===> Test : (unsaved)
groovy:000> t.foo
===> null
```

While direct assignment (through the setter method) works as expected:

```
groovy:000> c.foo = 'bar'
===> bar
groovy:000> c.foo
===> bar
```

Is there a way to make the map constructor accept transient fields?

---

Or rather: is there a better way to persist a `Map` as a single JSON-encoded DB field, rather than the method shown in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106384/persisting-maps-and-lists-of-properties-as-json-in-grails)?

Here's the complete example:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class JsonMap {
    Map data
    String dataAsJSON

    static transients = ['data']
    def afterLoad()      { data = JSON.parse(dataAsJSON) }
    def beforeValidate() { dataAsJSON = data as JSON }
}
```

I can set `data` using the setter (which will then be converted into `dataAsJSON`) but not using the map constructor.

Comment: Transient properties are not persisted. I think that this is impossible this way.

Comment: I know they are not persisted. If you read the linked question, the Map property is declared transient on purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map constructor in GORM uses the data binding mechanism, and transient properties are not data-bindable by default. But you can override this using the [bindable constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html)

```
class Test {
    //...
    String foo
    static transients = ['foo']

    static constraints = {
        foo bindable:true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also replied to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25760372/4018614), that you don't need json conversion to achieve what you need. However, If you need json conversion badly, why don't you implement it in your getters/setters?

```
class Test {
    String propsAsJson

    static transients = ['props']

    public Map getProps() {
        return JSON.parse(propsAsJson)
    }

    public void setProps(Map props) {
        propsAsJson = props as JSON
    }
}

//So you can do
Test t = new Test(props : ["foo" : "bar"])
t.save()
```

In this way you encapsulate the conversion stuff, and in DB you have your properties as Json.

Comment: Wouldn't this convert the data to Json every time you modify the property verses only converting it when you save?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your case by adding the JSON-conversion methods to your domain class, they should have nothing to do with GORMing:

```
class Test {
    String title

    void titleFromJSON( json ){ 
      title = json.toStringOfSomeKind()
    }

    def titleAsJSON(){ 
      new JSON( title )
    }

}
```

Comment: This provides less functionality than the existing afterLoad / beforeValidate method, and does not solve the issue of setting the transient value using the map constructor.