# Gradle fails when use def in constructor

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy

In class

```
class Variable{
   String name
   def value
}
```

When I do it in eclipse works fine...

```
Variable variable = new Variable(name:"A",value:3)
```

But, when I do gradle build, compiler ignores value parameter for constructor and my tests fail.

To work, I need:

```
Variable variable = new Variable(name:"A")
variable.value = 3
```

Somebody have got this situation yet?

Comment: what do your errors say? And why can't you use `Integer value`?

Comment: Cause this field is a Object. I'll receive any value. There's no erros. Just value is not setted.

Comment: have you tried using 'Object value'? obviously Groovy doesn't like you doing this.

Comment: I changed to Object but not work yet

Comment: idk. if you look at [this](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5074327900782592) snippet, it all works fine. even trying to sign 2nd value later worked. So.. are your configs allright?

Comment: Yes, when running groovy directly works fine. The trouble happens when I'm building in gradle.
`gradle build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was neither groovy nor gradle.
Trouble was grails, that not bind transients fields in constructor.
My question was not complete. Sorry. Thanks [Mikelis Baltruks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233197/mikelis-baltruks) for your help.

To solve, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749101/grails-setting-transient-fields-in-the-map-constructor)

Comment: then you should either accept your own answer or delete this post, so it doesn't "hang" in the air unanswered. btw - I just [more carefully] read your question again. missed most of the specifics when first commented. :D

Comment: Thanks.  
But I cant accept as correct yet. I must wait 2 days.  
;D Obrigado.